# the form refresh the page after the second submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

I'm having trouble with the send message form, but the issue is strange since when I initially submitted it, the page didn't refresh; yet, when I submitted it again, the form refreshed and the sent data was added to the url as a querystring.

After the second submit it does that

http://unified-animal-shelter.test/chat/52?_token=idIOk5Dq1U5MVulDeGgQSztefVWmTHZlTjtCFkaq&message=helloworld&touserId=52&roomid=2

More debugging revealed that the issue is with the HTML portion, so I deleted the javascript and focused directly on the area where the issue is occurring.

old html code which working

```
 <div class="messages-chat" id="container-message">
        @foreach ($messages as $message)
        
        @if ($message->from->user_id == Auth::id())
       
                
                <div class="message text-only">
                    <div class="response">
                        <p class="text">{{$message->message}}</p>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p class="time my_time">{{$message->created_at->format('h:i:s A')}} </p>
                @else
                <div class="message">
                    <div class="photo" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1438761681033-6461ffad8d80?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80);">
                        <div class="online"></div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="text">{{$message->message}} </p>
                </div>
                    <p class="time">{{$message->created_at->format('h:i:s A')}}</p>
                @endif
            @endforeach
            
            
            
            
        </div>
      
           
        <div class="bottom-0 w-full" dir="rtl">
            <form class="w-100 bg-red-500" id="form">
                @csrf
                <input type="text" class="write-message" name="message" id="inputMessage" placeholder="Type your message here">
                <input type="text" id="touserId" name="touserId" value="{{$user->user_id}}" hidden>
                <input type="text" hidden id="room-id" name="roomid" value="{{$room_id}}">
                <input type="submit" class="w-full h-full bg-red-500">
            </form>
        </div>
```

new ui which cause the problem somehow

```
     <div class="bg-white flex items-center">
        <div class="flex-col overflow-y-auto h-700">
    
            <div class="flex bg-primary p-4">
                <div class="bg-white rounded-l-lg p-3 flex flex-col justify-between relative">
                    <img src="https://api.dicebear.com/5.x/identicon/svg?seed={{rand()}}" class="w-16" alt="avatar">
                    <p class="bg-white absolute bottom-0">27/2/2002</p>
                </div>
                <div class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center bg-white p-4 space-y-4">
                    <h1 class="text-2xl">Abdulaziz</h1>
                    <p id="last-message">السلام عليكم القط هذا فيه امراض شي ؟</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    
    @if ($selectedUser)
        
    
        <div class="w-full h-700 relative">
            <div class="text-center flex items-center text-3xl p-3 bg-primary">
                <img src="https://api.dicebear.com/5.x/identicon/svg?seed={{rand()}}" class="w-16 bg-white rounded" alt="">
                <h1 class="w-full text-white">{{$user->display_name}}</h1>
                <button class="text-red-500 bg-white p-3 rounded">بلغ</button>
                
            </div>
            <div class="h-600 overflow-y-auto pb-10" id="container-message">
                @foreach ($messages as $message)
                    
                @if ($message->from->user_id == auth()->id())
                <div dir="rtl" class="p-8">
                    <p class="bg-blue-200 w-60 text-center p-3 rounded break-words">{{$message->message}}</p>
                </div>
               @else
               <div dir="ltr" class="p-8">
                    <p class="bg-gray-300 w-60 text-center p-3 rounded break-words">{{$message->message}}</p>
                </div>
                @endif {{--$message->from->user_id if --}}
                @endforeach
               
                
                
               
                <div class="absolute bottom-0 w-full" dir="rtl">
                    <form id="form">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="text" placeholder="محتوى الرسالة" id="inputMessage" name="message" class="w-full bg-gray-300 p-4 outline-none border border-t-2 focus:bg-white">
                        <input type="text" id="touserId" name="touserId" value="{{$user->user_id}}" hidden>
                        <input type="text" hidden id="room-id" name="roomid" value="{{$room_id}}">
                        <button type="submit" id="submit-button" class="absolute left-0 ml-3 mt-3 bg-blue-400 text-white rounded-full text-center w-10 h-10"><i class="fa-solid fa-paper-plane mt-2 mr-1"></i></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </div>
        @endif {{--Selected User if --}}
       </div>
```

Comment: Why are you making that AJAX request, without caring what response it gets, at all? What does the `create_message` function do?

Comment: @CBroe Hello, I'm trying to get better. Thanks for the advice, but the issue isn't with ajax because it sends the request to /send and saves it in the database. Instead, the strange behavior I described above occurs when a user submits a form twice, the second time refreshing the page, adding the create message function to the question above.

Comment: Can't tell you what is going on based on just those snippets. I'd start by keeping on eye on the browser console, perhaps some error occurring prevents it from preventing the event default action the second time.

Comment: @CBroe it refresh the page l cant see what is the error l tried using trycatch and the same thing is happening

Comment: _"it refresh the page l cant see what is the error"_ - your browser console should have a setting to keep the log across different requests, go find and enable that.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for keeping up for me l tried your solution but the error is staying the same now the errors shows in all request but there nothing that output

Comment: _What_ error? If you are getting errors in console, please quote them verbatim.

Comment: @CBroe that the problem im not getting any error works fine on the first submit but the second submit it does not l have the same project in github with old ui it works fine even if submit 100 times it dont refresh but with the new ui doesn't

Comment: Well then you'll need to debug some more, this isn't currently answerable with the info we got. If it is not some JavaScript error breaking the functionality, then perhaps somehow the event handler got removed from the form or something.

Comment: @CBroe l have added the old ui code with the javascript can you take a look maybe there is something that l didnt see changed

Comment: I rolled back your edit, because it changes the context of the question and our already on-going discussion, when you now remove the code you had shown so far, and replace it with something else entirely. If you have information to _add_, then please do that without removing all the previous context.

Comment: "the page didn't refresh;" - why should it? There's no code given that refreshes the page. Also, can you check whether this is a JS problem, a HTML problem, a PHP problem, or a Laravel problem? I highly doubt that all of these techniques are involved in the problem itself, especially as you haven't shared any PHP code

Comment: @NicoHaase l added send message function on the sendMessage Controller

Comment: @NicoHaase I am aware of the reason for my inquiry as to why this behavior is occurring even though it dont happen in the old code.

Comment: "it does that" - what is that? Please explain what is happening, and what you've tried to resolve the problem

Comment: @NicoHaase hello nico More debugging revealed that the issue is with the HTML portion, so I deleted the javascript and focused directly on the area where the issue is occurring. i tried the same javascript and the same controller everything works on the old ui but when l replace it with the new ui it breaks after the second submit l suspect tailwind is doing something that breaks it and l dont know why

Comment: Hello everyone, the issue has been resolved, but I would like some of you to clarify why it occurred in the first place. The issue was that the form was inside the container-message div. I just removed the form from the div and placed it elsewhere, and it now functions as intended.